# Unable to open file in VSCode, simple compile error also

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I just installed VSCODE, created a simple HelloWorld.ts file and when I try and compile it says it can't find the file?

The compile error is:

; expected
HelloWorld (3,9)

Not sure what is going on here?

[image]

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true
    }  
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    "args": ["HelloWorld.ts"],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Comment: what's the content of tsconfig.json?

Comment: @toskv I updated it.  If I click on create file, it says "ENOENT no such file or directory, mkdir 'c:\dev\vscode\C:'

Comment: it's probably something to do with the args part, could you try just sending an empty array as the arguments?

Comment: tsconfig.json should take care of the files you want to compile.

Comment: @toskv if I make args empty [] in tasks.json, then it doesn't compile anything.  If I mess out the file it doesn't report an error.

Comment: I just want to see it run somehow also...

Comment: you should be able to open a command line and run tsc in the folder containing tscconfig.json. :)

Comment: it seems to be an issue with the vs code task runner. I was able to run my projects by giving an empty args list.

Comment: @toskv why doesn't cntrol-shift-b compile it though? why do I have to use the command line?

Comment: the task runner calls tsc for you, but for some reason the command it generates is wrong. my guess is that the file given in args is not ok. :( it would help if you could get the command generated by the task runner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99848/discussion-between-toskv-and-cool-breeze).